# samba server - share root

Tags: raspbian, windows, samba

I've set up samba on raspbian Jessie, and I am able to get to the "pi" user's folder from a windows box.

I want to be able to get to the `/etc/` directory from windows because I want to edit conf files in the warm bosom of notepad instead of using nano. I've set up the below with the path specifically pointing at `/etc` and with just `/.`

```
[root]
   read only = no
   locking = no
   path = /etc
   guest ok = yes
```

and I gave All users write access to the `/etc` folder with `chmod`. I can see the `\\raspberrypi\root` share in windows, and it prompts me for my credentials. but then it says it's not accessible, because either I don't have permissions, or I have another connection to the server with a different username.

I've searched around the internet for this, but it's difficult searching for "raspbian etc" because every configuration tutorial in the world seems to involve the `/etc` folder.

Comment: How did you give all users permission? `sudo chmod 777 /`?

Comment: I think it was sudo chmod ar+w /etc. something like that. but started over with a fresh image to try out your answer.

Comment: Which file did you just show?

Comment: Are you on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using Notepad++ to edit the said files, setting up samba is just overkill. There is a plugin in Notepad++ called nppFTP which you can use to login to the Raspberry Pi over SFTP and then edit and save any file in `/etc` or any directory for that matter. For an added bonus, you could setup ssh key based authentication for the root user so that you can login to SFTP with the root user and not have to change permissions in `/etc` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I have my root folder shared on my Pi. My config is a bit different than yours:

```
[root]
    comment = root
    path=/
    browseable=YES
    writeable=YES
    valid users= pi, root
    only guest=no
    create mask=0777
    directory mask=07777
    public=no
    force user = root
```

`valid users` makes it so that the user `pi` and the user `root` have permission to access `/`. `force user` makes it so that all files written over `smb` will be done be `root`, even though `pi` can still write files, it will look like `root` did it.

Make sure you do:

`sudo smbpasswd -a pi` and `sudo smbpasswd -a root`

after you edit this file, so you can set a password for both users.

NOTE: **Never allow guest/public access to your `root` folder, it's not only outrageously insecure, but it's probably bad practice to broadcast your entire filesystem to anyone with a computer in the area.**

Comment: patrick, I copied and pasted your config, and created the pi and root smb users. now when I open  \\raspberrypi\root, I am not prompted for credentials, and I can see all the folders underneath. but when I try to open any of them, I get a 'not accessible... unexpected error occurred". I've restarted the samba service as well.

Comment: Which file is this config located in?

Comment: @SDsolar `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

Answer (score 0):

I would have used Filezilla (SFTP graphically) and then copied, backed up, edited and sent back the update.

Answer (score -1):

Change the path of the directory to / so you can access every thing